# How can I run coroutine function on Program exit on python?

Tags: python, coroutine

I have to run coroutine function on program exit in python. How can I run it?
I've tried to run using atexit module, but it raised error 'coroutine is not callable'

Comment: Show your use of `atexit` that lead to that error.

Comment: atexit.register(some_coroutine()) #I'm using python3.6 so I can't use lambda : asyncio.run()